# How does mirror reflection affect laser beam coherence?

Tags: optics, photons, reflection, laser, coherence

I am an engineer that uses 10.6 micon laser beams to damage material. I am not a physicist so be gentle with your answers please.
Two adjacent photons with their wave phases locked strike a 45 degree mirror. After reflection their left right positions will be swapped  but one photon will strike the reflecting surface before the other. Does this have an effect on the phasing between them? My simple engineering logic tells me the unimaginable size of a photon relative to the huge 10.6 micron wavelength means the phase shift would be very small and require many reflections to destroy the beam coherency.

Comment: Imagine that there is a detector downstream from the mirror, perpendicular to the arriving photons.  Which one gets there first?   BTW, thinking of a photon as a very tiny ball of something works for many situations.  But it is not a correct picture, and can lead to frustration at best, wrong answers at worst.  One reason:  how can a small particle have phase?  It might work for your question, but I'm not sure because I don't quite follow your reasoning.

Comment: They both travel the same net distance … so phase is unchanged.  Many engineers worry about phase …. because they were taught interference in high school, it practice it does not matter.  2 photons never cancel …. All energy emitted by the lasers will be absorbed.

Comment: Spatial coherence (spreading) is more important. The mirror is not perfect, the air is present, the beam has a spread with distance, these are typically what you are up against.

Comment: I don't think a photon is much smaller than a wavelength, nor much bigger